# Non Isolated Singularity

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to identify the type of singularity in the function $\frac{e^z-1}{\sin^3{z}}$.  This function has a singularity every $k\pi$ and thus the singularity is not isolated.

How does one classify a non-isolated singularity?  Do the normal methods of pole, essentail, and removeable apply?

Comment: It has poles of order $3$.

Comment: How did you get that conclusion?  If I take the taylor series of the function, I get poles of order 2.

Comment: @Berci Also, does this mean that the pole is isolated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(z) = \frac{e^z-1}{\sin^3z}$ then, as you found, $f$ has singularities at $z=\pi k$.
For $k=0$ we have:
$$
\lim_{z \to 0}z^2f(z) = 1
$$
and for $k \ne 0$
$$
\lim_{z \to \pi k}z^3f(z) = (-1)^{k}(e^{\pi k}-1)
$$

then $f$ has a pole of order $2$ at $z=0$ and poles of order $3$ at $z=\pi k, \space k\ne0$

Notice that for every $z=\pi k$ there is a disc around $z$ that doesn't contain any other singularity, so they are isolated. This is not the case for $g(z) = \frac{1}{\sin\frac{1}{z}}$ for example where there isn't a punctured neighborhood of $z=0$ where $g$ is analytic.